# grep within in R-function

Tags: r, regex

I want to write an R-function (using grep) that allows me to do an exact pattern match, but I am having trouble figuring out how to denote the exact end of the match (using $).  More specifically, consider  the following:

```
data(mtcars)
mtcars$a <- row.names(mtcars)

mtcars[grep("Merc 450SL", mtcars$a), ]  
[1] "Merc 450SL"  "Merc 450SLC"

mtcars[grep("Merc 450SL$", mtcars$a), ]
[1] "Merc 450SL"
```

So, I want to write the latter into a function, where it includes an exact pattern match, with the dollar sign. I can do a simple pattern match (like the first example):

```
 grep.f <- function(x){
      b <- grep(x, mtcars$a, fixed=TRUE) 
      print(mtcars[b,"a"])
      }

 grep.f("Merc 450SL")
 [1] "Merc 450SL"  "Merc 450SLC"
```

The function obviously chokes when I change the second line to `b <- grep(x$, mtcars$a, fixed = TRUE)`, but I am stuck as to how I should accomplish this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `grep(paste0(x, "$"), mtcars$a, value=TRUE)`

Comment: That is really clever, and the reliability of answers (posted within seconds) is amazing.  Thx!

Comment: You may also be interested in `match(x, mtcars$a)` or `intersect(x, mtcars$a)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can paste the `$` at the end of the variable, like this:

```
grep.f <- function(x) {
  b <- grep(paste0(x, '$'), mtcars$a) 
  print(mtcars[b, "a"])
}
grep.f("Merc 450SL")
```

And instead of printing, it's better to return the values directly:

```
grep.f <- function(x) {
  grep(paste0(x, '$'), mtcars$a, value=T)
}
grep.f("Merc 450SL")
```